# css arrow: how is the arrow's tail drawn?

Tags: css

I have been going through how different shapes can be drawn by css. I have encountered the following css code which draws a small arrow shape:

```
#curvedarrow {
  position: relative;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 9px solid transparent;
  border-right: 9px solid red;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(10deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(10deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(10deg);
}
#curvedarrow:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border: 0 solid transparent;
  border-top: 3px solid red;
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 0;
  top: -12px;
  left: -9px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

I completely understand how the tip of the arrow is drawn as I hide the tail (arrow:after) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-do-css-triangles-work) really helped me a lot to understand most of the shapes drawn.

Yet I am stuck how the border is used to draw the tail.[image] (I hid the tip by setting it transparent). Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rwg7L97o/1/) also.

I see that he set only left-top corner border radius by   `border-radius: 20px 0 0 0;`, but why the end of the left side of that tail finishes getting smaller but the right side is just like a cut?

I thought that, okay only left-top side corner is drawn(when border-radius takes 4 values, first one is the left-top then top-right etc etc.. [ref](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp)), so if I add right-top side, it should double the length of the shape yet getting the volume decreased. My second statement is correct, but the length does not change at all. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nq2pah8u/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically this is made with a couple of things. I broke down the steps in the following code snippet:

```css
body {
font-family: sans-serif;
}

#circle {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#circle2 {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  border-radius: 50% 0 0 0;
}

#circle3 {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border: solid;
  border-color: red transparent transparent transparent;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-radius: 50% 0 0 0;
}

#circle4 {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border: solid;
  border-color: red transparent transparent transparent;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-radius: 50% 0 0 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#circle5 {
  height: 10px;
  width: 12px;
  border: solid;
  border-color: red transparent transparent transparent;
  border-width: 5px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 50% 0 0 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#circle6 {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border: solid;
  border-color: red transparent transparent transparent;
  border-width: 3px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#square {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border: 5px solid;
  border-color: red green grey black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#square2 {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border: 5px solid;
  border-color: red green grey black;
  border-radius: 50% 0;
}

#square3 {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border: 5px solid;
  border-color: red green grey black;
  border-radius: 50% 0;
  border-width: 5px 0;
}

.wrapper {
  background: #eeeeee;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  1. Create a circle using border-radius
</p>
<div id="circle">
</div>
<br>
<p>
  2. Change the border-radius so that only one corner has it.
</p>
<div id="circle2">
</div>
<br>
<p>
  3. Remove all the other borders
</p>
<div id="circle3">
</div>
<br>
<p>
  4. Rotate the whole thing
</p>
<div id="circle4">
</div>
<br>
<p>
  5. Set the border-width to zero for all borders except border-top <br>(This creates the "cut" effect you described earlier, as the border-width goes from 5 to zero (from top to left)
</p>
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>
    For further demonstration: The combination of a varying border-radius and border-width creates this effect.</p>
  <p>
    Basic borders:
  </p>
  <div id="square"></div>
  <br>
  <p>
    Varying border-radius:
  </p>
  <div id="square2"></div>
  <br>
  <p>
    Varying border-radius and border-width:
  </p>
  <div id="square3"></div>
  <br>
  <p>
   Result:
  </p>
<div id="circle5">
</div>
</div>
<br>
<p>
  6. Change up the values
</p>
<div id="circle6">
</div>
<br>
<p>
  7. And you're done!
</p>
<div id="curvedarrow"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you pretty much can read CSS like a step by step procedure

```
#curvedarrow:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border: 0 solid transparent; // make sure NO border is displayed
                               //   it also makes the size of the 
                               //   borders = 0 in order to be 
                               //   able to do that "pointy" effect at
                               //   the end of the tail

  border-top: 3px solid red;   // make a border on the top of the box and
                               // make it 3 pixels thick. this will be the
                               // final size of the transition

  border-radius: 20px 0 0 0;   // round the top left corner of the box
                               // (the one you actually see) with a 
                               // radius of 20 pixels. Since in goes from 
                               // 0 pxiels to 3 during this transformation,
                               // it will smoothly do so. Resulting in 
                               // a "pointy" effect for the tail. if you
                               // want a staring tail, just use the same 
                               // border size for the whole border

  //those are basicaly just placing the tail at the right place
  top: -12px;
  left: -9px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;

  // rotate the tail 45 deg to the right.
  // since each browser my act differently to `transform: rotate(45deg)`
  // the code here just makes sure each browser uses it's own rotation
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```